# Finding memberships with 'Status Override' set

Tags: civimember, search

I was asked recently if there was a way to find all members who have the 'Status Override' setting turned on. I didn't see an option in the advanced search or member search:

[image: Find Memberships]

As an alternative, I made a smart group that finds all **Primary Members** that have a **Membership Status** of "Current" and a membership **End Date** in the past (e.g. "Prior to previous day"). This should find all memberships that are hard-coded as "Current" although they are technically expired (right?) but is not actually finding all overridden memberships.

Is there a way to search on whether the membership status is overridden, regardless of what the status is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CiviCRM has a search builder and the field Override status is available in the search builder.

[image: Search builder status override]

Comment: Oops--same answer seconds apart!

Comment: Andrew, I'll give the answer to Jaap since he beat you by a few seconds. ;) Somehow I spaced out on the Search Builder -- thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Search Builder will do this.  Select `Membership` `Status Override` `=` `Yes` and it'll return the contacts with that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is in 4.7/master. I submitted [CRM-17364](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17364) with patches, but an alternative/tidier [patch](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6966) was accepted into master only.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to refer to a patch. And it doesn't make sense to refer to a version which is not even released

Comment: It lets them know that it's coming at least!